# Запрос в mssql node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

Проблема состоит в том, что я не знаю возможно ли как-то обратиться к mssql соединению из различный файлов проекта чтобы сделать query-запрос к базе данных после того, как в index.js я уже инициализировал соединение.

**index.js:**

```
const mssql = require('mssql');
const { mssqlConfig } = require('./utils/db');

async function start() {
    try {
        await mssql.connect(mssqlConfig);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

start();
```

Например, в роутах я пишу

```
const mssql = require('mssql');
const { mssqlConfig } = require('../utils/db');

(async function sql() {
        try {
            const pool = await mssql.connect(mssqlConfig);
            const result = await pool.request()
                .query('select * from table');
            pool.close();
            return result.recordset;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('SQL error', err);
        }
    })();
```

И получаю ошибку, что соединение уже есть, и прежде чем открывать новое, нужно закрыть предыдущее:

> SQL error Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close()
>   first.

Понятно, что я могу сразу же в index.js закрыть его, но если есть способ общаться к этому соединению с других файлов, то это было бы намного практичнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получилось сделать это следующим образом:

**index.js**

```
mssql.connect(mssqlConfig).then(pool => {
    return pool;
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

В любом файле проекта я делаю следующее:

```
const mssql = require('mssql');

const sqlquery = async () => {
          try {
              const mssqlRequest = await new mssql.Request();
              const result = await mssqlRequest.query('select * from table');
              return result.recordset;
          } catch (err) {
              console.error('SQL error', err);
          }
      };

sqlquery();
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно вынести в `index.js`:

```
export const connection = await mssql.connect(mssqlConfig);
```